# Directive to format date in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a span in ng-repeat as follows:

```
span(humanize-date="{{file.date}}"
```

I'm to create a directive so that, directive changes the date format

```
directive('humanizeDate', [
  function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<div value="{{formattedDate}}"/>',
      replace: true,
      scope: {
        formattedDate: '=humanizeDate'
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        return scope.formatedDate = moment.duration(scope.humanizeDate).humanize();
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

just use:

```
<span ng-non-bindable>{{1288323623006 | date:'medium'}}</span>
```

here is more information about
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

hope to help

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `{{}}` while you are using `=` inside your directive which indicated two way binding.

It should be direct variable reference rather than `{{}}`

```
span(humanize-date="file.date"
```

**OR**

Other way would be you could use `@` in your directive isolated scope as your are giving `{{}}` with expression to attribute which indicated one way binding.

```
scope: {
  formattedDate: '@humanizeDate'
},
```

Comment: @user3840211 does it helped you?